# Rhino Mocks Exception from Castle Dynamic Proxy When Mocking Generics with Where

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks, castle-dynamicproxy

I have an exception from Rhino Mocks 3.6.0 and 3.6.1 when mocking the following interface:

```
public interface ic
{
    IComponentConfig<TImpl> Bob<TSvc, TImpl>()
        where TImpl : TSvc;
}
```

I can confirm that when removing the Generic "where" association, it will correctly mock.

The Stack trace points firmly at Castle Dynamic Proxy:

> System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled by user code
>    HResult=-2147024885
>    Message=An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
>    Source=mscorlib
>    StackTrace:
>         at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
>         at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()
>         at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()
>         at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.BuildType()
>         at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.Emitters.AbstractTypeEmitter.BuildType()
>         at Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.InterfaceProxyWithTargetGenerator.GenerateCode(Type proxyTargetType, Type[] interfaces, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
>         at Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder.CreateInterfaceProxyTypeWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
>         at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyTypeWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options)
>         at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget(Type interfaceToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
>         at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.MockInterface(CreateMockState mockStateFactory, Type type, Type[] extras)
>         at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.CreateMockObject(Type type, CreateMockState factory, Type[] extras, Object[] argumentsForConstructor)
>         at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.DynamicMock[T](Object[] argumentsForConstructor)
>         at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.<>c__DisplayClass7`1.<GenerateMock>b__6(MockRepository r)
>         at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.CreateMockInReplay[T](Func`2 createMock)
>         at Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.GenerateMock[T](Object[] argumentsForConstructor)
>         at XXXXX.ConfigTestBase.SetUp() in c:\git\MyFork\Workspace\Db.Montage.Common.Tests\Config\ConfigTestBase.cs:line 27
>    InnerException:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old bug in old version of DynamicProxy that has been fixed long time ago.

Unfortunately it seems Rhino Mocks still hasn't updated it's dependency on DynamicProxy to a more recent version with this issue fixed.

I think your two options are to build a custom version od Rhino (against new DynamicProxy) or to use another mocking framework that is using more recent version of DynamicProxy (like NSubstitute, FakeItEasy or Moq)